Given normal subgroup $H\triangleleft G$ with prime index $p$, then $G\cong H\ \rtimes\langle\alpha\rangle.$
Update. Please see accepted answer for update to this question. It is in fact not true, and a very clear counter-example exists.

Statement. Let $G$ denote some artbirary finite group. Given normal subgroup $H\triangleleft G$ with prime index $p$, then $G\cong H\ \rtimes\langle\alpha\rangle$ for some $\alpha\in G$ (with $o(\alpha)=p$).
My guess... is that this statement will be true. Why so? Since $G/H$ has prime order, it follows that there will exist an element $\beta\in G$ -- which we'll define as being the representative of the generator for $G/H$ (recall: prime order $\Rightarrow$ cyclic) -- with order $p^{a}$ for some $a\in\mathbb{N}^{>0}$. If we let $\alpha=\beta^{p^{a-1}}$, then we reached the desired result as a consequence of (i) $H\triangleleft G$ and (ii) $H\langle\alpha\rangle=G$.
I appreciate any and all help I can get. Thanks!

If you let $\alpha=\beta^{p^{a-1}},$ then when $a >1,$ $\alpha\in H,$ this $\alpha$ can't a be a candidate for the decomposition of $G$ as a semi-direct product.

Isn't $S_5 \times C_7$ a counterexample because $7 \nmid \vert \operatorname{Aut} (S_5) \vert$?

@Tsoshamry I see. Overlooked that, my bad. Thanks though! Appreciate it.

Consider the cyclic group $G$ of order $p^2$, generated by $x\in G.$ Let $H=<x^p>,$ then $H$ is of index $p$ in $G.$ The elements in $G$ that are of order $p$ are ${x^p, x^{2p},\cdots,x^{(p-1)p}},$ which are exactly the non-identity elements in $H$.

@RobertShore I do not believe that would be a counter-example since $S_5\times C_7\cong S_5\rtimes_{\alpha} C_7$ given we let $\alpha:C_7\to\text{Aut}(S_5)$ denote the trivial homomorphism.

Note that the statement is indeed true if $p$ does not divide the order of $H$.

Upon having read through some of the above comments, in fact the proof I presented was not true, as well a counter-example exists to disprove the statement.

Problem with proof. Since $\beta^{p}\in H$ (by property of being the representative of the generator), it follows immediately that $\alpha\in H$. Hence, $H\langle\alpha\rangle\neq G$.

Counter-Example. $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.


